# Discarding Brown Forsythe if homogeneity of variance in population has been shown in other dataset?

Tags: anova, variance, heteroscedasticity, kruskal-wallis-test

For the analysis of my experiment I used 2 one-way ANOVA tests. Both datasets were acquired from the exact same samples (and therefore population). They are merely two different parameters acquired.

In one ANOVAs the Brown-Forsythe test was statistically insignificant. However, in the other ANOVA analysis the control group is (due to overcorrection as part of the measurement) always zero and now the Brown-Forsythe test is significant. Can I discard the Brown-Forsythe test and argue that Brown-Forsythe test was negative in the other  tests and therefore homogeneity of variance can be assumed.

Or is the only valid option to use Kruskal-Wallis H test?

Here is exemplary data:

C: 0 / 0 / 0 / 0

G1: 0,025 / 0,066 / 0,003

G2: 0,006 / 0,001

G3: 0 / 0 / 0 / 0

G4: 0 / 0 / 0